# How to change range slider min,max and step values using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the min,max and step values of a slider using Javascript. I know we can set them as range properties in HTML, but I am specifically looking for an option to use javascript. because my range will vary depends upon condition.

HLML:

```
<input type="range" id="LoanAmntRange" class="LoanAmntRange">
<input type="text" id="LoanAmntText"></input>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

$('#LoanAmntText').val($(LoanAmntRange).val());

 $('input[type="range"]').on('input change', function() {

$("#LoanAmntRange").slider('value', 50, 80);

$('#LoanAmntText').val($(this).val()); 


  });
});


$('#LoanAmntText').on("change",function(){


var val = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d\+]/g,"");   // check only for digits
$('#LoanAmntRange').val(val).trigger("change");

});
```

I was going through some of the old discussion and and they have mentioned that the values can be adjusted using below options

Adjust min and max:

`$("#LoanAmntRange").slider('value', 50, 80)`;

Adjust step value:

`$("#LoanAmntRange").slider("option", "step", 10);`

But its not working for me. Is there anyway I can do it ?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k7qf58ex/1/

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-min  you should checkout the api to see how they set/change the options

Comment: And your fiddle is not working because you did not include jQuery UI.

Comment: @Taplar : Thanks I have included the jquery UI. And the options are set correctly, but its not working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/k7qf58ex/15/

Comment: `$( "LoanAmntRange" )`  you have invalid selectors.  It also looks like you are trying to go straight to using the option method, without ever initializing the slider.  You should initialize the slider with those options, as the API shows.

Comment: Have you tried `$.prop` http://api.jquery.com/prop/ ?

Comment: this is  working if I remove the  type="range" and use div id.

Comment: @acr so this question is solved, right?